# Failed to lookup view "cdap" in views directories -- cdap_assets login_assets

Tags: cdap

We have cloned cdap ui repo from github.

https://github.com/cdapio/cdap-ui

Below is the node and npm versions

```
node -v
v10.24.1


npm -version
6.14.12
```

We are able to run npm install and is successful. However, when we hit the CDAP UI, few directories lookup failed.

```
[2021-10-18T07:26:40.832] [INFO] default - Starting CDAP UI ...
[2021-10-18T07:26:40.848] [INFO] default - Trying to connect to CDAP Router using URL http://127.0.0.1:11015/ping
[2021-10-18T07:26:40.860] [WARN] default - Unable to connect to CDAP Router. Will keep trying to connect in background.
[2021-10-18T07:26:40.862] [INFO] default - UI using theme file: /media/cdap-ui/packaged/server_dist/server/config/themes/default.json
[2021-10-18T07:26:40.864] [WARN] default - Unable to find favicon at path /media/cdap-ui/packaged/public/cdap_dist/cdap_assets/img/favicon.png
[2021-10-18T07:26:40.864] [ERROR] default - Favicon missing! Please run `gulp build`
[2021-10-18T07:26:40.919] [INFO] default - CDAP UI listening on port 11011
Error: Failed to lookup view "cdap" in views directories "/media/cdap-ui/packaged/public/cdap_dist/cdap_assets", "/media/cdap-ui/packaged/public/login_dist/login_assets", "/media/cdap-ui/packaged/public/dll", "/media/cdap-ui/packaged/public/dist" or "/media/cdap-ui/packaged/public/common_dist"
    at Function.render (webpack:///./node_modules/express/lib/application.js?:580:17)
    at ServerResponse.render (webpack:///./node_modules/express/lib/response.js?:1012:7)
    at eval (webpack:///./server/express.js?:636:9)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (webpack:///./node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js?:95:5)
    at next (webpack:///./node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js?:137:13)
    at next (webpack:///./node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js?:131:14)
    at next (webpack:///./node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js?:131:14)
    at next (webpack:///./node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js?:131:14)
    at next (webpack:///./node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js?:131:14)
    at next (webpack:///./node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js?:131:14)
```

Any idea what is the issue and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't run the full UI build. First you should make sure all dependencies are installed:

```
yarn
bower i
```

If you're interested in doing active development, you can run the compilation watchers and the server with one command:

```
yarn dev
```

If you aren't doing development and don't need the watchers, you can run the following commands to build and run the server:

```
yarn cdap-full-build
yarn start
```

Sorry, it looks like the README is not very up-to-date.